# Axiom getTextAsStream without caching Parser has already reached end of the document. No siblings found

Tags: java, apache-axis, axiom

I'm using Axiom in Axis2 to extract the text from a large base64Binary section of the SOAP message.  My receiver is not using MTOM, and uses `OMElement.getTextAsStream( false )` to extract the text.  The code looks something like this:

```
final Iterator<OMElement> childrenIterator = uploadFile.getChildElements();
while ( childrenIterator.hasNext() )
{
    final OMElement element = childrenIterator.next();
    if ( "fileID".equals( element.getLocalName() ) )
    {
        fileID = element.getText();
    }
    // fileContent contains a large base64Binary block
    else if ( "fileContent".equals( element.getLocalName() ) )
    {
        Reader reader = element.getTextAsStream( false );

        final char[] buf = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int len = 0;
        while ( (len = reader.read( buf ) ) >= 0 )
        {
            if ( len > 0 )
            {
                // Process chunk here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A sample XML would look like

```
<uploadFile>
    <fileID>id</fileID>
    <fileContent>~500kB of base64 data</fileContent>
</uploadFile>
```

I'm getting this exception on the `childrenIterator.hasNext()` line after the base64Binary data has been read:

```
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Parser has already reached end of the document. No siblings found
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:359)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:69)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMFilterIterator.hasNext(OMFilterIterator.java:54)
```

I've done some investigating, and it's definitely related to the fact that I'm setting cache to `false` when calling `getTextAsStream()`.  I need to do this because the potential size of the base64 data could be hundreds of megabytes.

The problem seems to be that `TextFromElementReader` advances the underlying `XMLStreamReader` to the END_ELEMENT event.  `OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling()` then calls `next()` on the underlying `XMLStreamReader` and gets the END_DOCUMENT event.  It seems like the `TextFromElementReader` needs to encounter the END_ELEMENT to know that it has reached the end of the text segment, but this leaves the underlying `XMLStreamReader` in the wrong state for `OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling()`.

Has anyone seen this error before?  Is it something wrong with the way I'm using Axiom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using getTextAsReader at all.  Instead, I iterated through the child text nodes and processed the text content in chunks that way.  The parser is configured to be non-coalescing, so I get reasonably sized text nodes rather than one big one.

```
OMNode child = omElement.getFirstOMChild();
while ( child != null )
{
    if ( child instanceof OMText )
    {
        // process 'child' text here

        final OMNode nextSibling = child.getNextOMSibling();
        child.detach();    // detach from OM to keep memory usage low
        child = nextSibling;
    }
}
```